# Rendering something on server side by taking input from frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have been asked to perform following task

1. Take a code input from frontend, i.e user would give his code on frontend (design for a web/landing page)
2. On backend we have many fields inside an api route

   ```
   route.get("/", (req, res) => {
       const fullName: "Varun Bindal"
       const contactNo = 9293939933
      const message = "Message I want to display"
    //Many more 
   }
   ```
3. Tell user a way where when we serve his code such that, he could dynamically access/assign the fields we have in the backend into his code

I did some googling and found the express officially recommends ejs for server side compilation of webpage

Can someone please help me figure out how we can achieve this?

Comment: Do you really need to create your page from the server code? Can't you just send the necessary data to the client and render the webpage on client side?

Comment: @RickyMo Yap, Apparently server side rendering is must.

Comment: So did you try ejs? I didn't use it before but it looks viable at a glance.

Comment: @RickyMo I haven't I am not sure about the flow

Comment: This question is very broad, and better suited to a forum or something else. SO is for specific questions, like if there's something you get stuck on when pursuing this project. Unless I've misunderstood your specific question--in which case, maybe restate.

Comment: Maybe you can try following some tutorial to get ejs working first. Then add your own things. Ask a more specific question when something does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can!
Firstly you must include ejs in your project, configure it in your server.js file for example, then you can call `res.render()` in your callback parameter on route.get().

In your html or javascript you can create a placeholder which gets populated.

Example (server):

```
route.engine('html', ejs.renderFile);
route.engine('js', ejs.renderFile);

route.get('/', (req, res) => res.render(path.resolve(__dirname, ' 
   ../ui/index.html'), {
    'myVal': 42,
}));
```

Example (client html, js, etc...):

```
<%= myVal %>
```